# Discontinuity of f and g

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity

Let $f:g:X\to \mathbb R$ be functions where $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$. If f is continuous at $a\in X$ and $f(a)\neq 0$, while $g$ is discontinuous at $a$. Prove or disprove that $fg$ is discontinuous at $a$.

After thinking for a while I think $fg$ should be discontinuous at $a$, and here is my argument (which I am not very confident about):

Consider $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|$ which equals to
$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(a)+f(x)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|$

$=\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)(g(x)-g(a))+(f(x)-f(a))(g(a)|$

Since $f$ is continuous at $a$,$(f(x)-f(a))g(a)\to 0$ as $x\to a$. Hence the limit equals to
$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)(g(x)-g(a))|=\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)||g(x)-g(a)|$ (**)

Now $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|f(a)|>0$. Since g is discontinuous at $a$, $\lim_{x\to a}|g(x)-g(a)|=0$ is not true. It follows that $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)||g(x)-g(a)|=0$ is not true. Thus $fg$ is discontinuous at a.

I am not very confident about the step I marked with (**) as I feel like there is no explicit use of similar arguments in my textbook, although I think it is most likely correct. I also intuitively feel like $fg$ might still be continuous at $a$

Answer (score 1):

If $fg$ were continuous at $a$, then $fg/f$ is also continuous at $a$, a contradiction.